# Poker software terms

Tags: software, terminology

I have just downloaded Poker Copilot to track my poker play, But I am unable to understand the terms mentioned in it while playing. For example, what do VPIP, PFR and AFQ mean? How do I analyse them? Can anyone explain it in detail?

Answer (score 2):

VPIP stands for "voluntary put in pot"

PFR stands for "pre-flop raising"

AFq is the agression factor (number of times you raise vs number of times you call)

All three are probably expressed as percentages. The accepted values for a decenet player vary depending on table size, game mode... so it's hard to set a general rule without further details